# merge duplicate values in slice

Tags: go, struct, slice

I have car struct with following structure:

```
type Car struct {
    Name      string
    Factories []string
}
```

I have a slice of car struct same as following:

```
cars := []Car{
     {
         Name: "sample-car"
         Factories: []string{"factory-1"}
     },
     {
         Name: "fast-car"
         Factories: []string{"factory-1"}
     },
     {
         Name: "sample-car"
         Factories: []string{"factory-2"}
     },
 }
```

I need to merge duplicate cars By keeping the names of two factories

```
cars := []Car{
     {
         Name: "sample-car"
         Factories: []string{"factory-1", "factory-2"}
     },
     {
         Name: "fast-car"
         Factories: []string{"factory-1"}
     },
 }
```

How can I get the above output?

edit: I try this but this is remove a factory, I want merge factories

```
m := make(map[int]bool)
uniqueCar := make([]Car, 0, len(cars))

for _, car := range cars {
    if _, ok := m[car.Name]; !ok {
        m[car.Name] = true
        uniqueCar = append(uniqueCar, val)
    }
}

return uniqueCar
```

Comment: There's no function to automatically do this, what problem are you having?

Comment: Using [`for`](https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/16) and [`append`](https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/15). What have you tried? What problem(s) did you encounter?

Comment: @JimB I can not merge factory names. I update my question

Comment: @Adrian i use for and append but i can not merge factory.

Comment: You're halfway there, you just forgot to append the factories.

Comment: @Adrian I do not know how to add the factory. Can you help to me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're very close, but you forgot to append the factories themselves:

```
m := make(map[string]Car)

for _, car := range cars {
    if v, ok := m[car.Name]; !ok {
        m[car.Name] = car
    } else {
        v.Factories = append(v.Factories, car.Factories)
        m[car.Name] = v
    }
}

uniqueCars = make([]Car, len(m))
for i, car := range m {
    uniqueCars[i] = car
}
```

You'll need to do a little more finagling if there's a chance for duplicate car/factory combinations to appear in your input and you don't want duplicate factories in your output. You'll also need to do more finagling if you want to keep the cars in their original order.

Comment: thanks for your answer. Why you dont use `m` in the second for ?

Comment: @Jack typo, it should be `m`. Fixed.